# VBA: how keep the list created through the Data Validation when reopening the spreadsheet the list remains created

Tags: excel, vba, list

I have the following code to create a list:

```
Sub list_date_inp1()
With Workbooks("TAB AUTO.xlsm").Sheets("input1").Range("B5:C5").Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:="mar/2008,jun/2008,set/2008,dez/2008,mar/2009,jun/2009,set/2009,dez/2009,mar/2010,jun/2010,set/2010,dez/2010,mar/2011,jun/2011,set/2011,dez/2011,mar/2012,jun/2012,set/2012,dez/2012,mar/2013,jun/2013,set/2013,dez/2013,mar/2014,jun/2014,set/2014,dez/2014,mar/2015,jun/2015,set/2015,dez/2015,mar/2016,jun/2016,set/2016,dez/2016,mar/2017,jun/2017,set/2017,dez/2017,mar/2018,jun/2018,set/2018,dez/2018,mar/2019,jun/2019,set/2019,dez/2019,mar/2020,jun/2020,set/2020,dez/2020,mar/2021,jun/2021,set/2021,dez/2021,mar/2022,jun/2022,set/2022,dez/2022,mar/2023,jun/2023,set/2023,dez/2023,mar/2024,jun/2024,set/2024," & _
"dez/2024,mar/2025,jun/2025,set/2025,dez/2025,mar/2026,jun/2026,set/2026,dez/2026,mar/2027,jun/2027,set/2027,dez/2027,mar/2028,jun/2028,set/2028,dez/2028,mar/2029,jun/2029,set/2029,dez/2029,mar/2030,jun/2030,set/2030,dez/2030,mar/2031,jun/2031,set/2031,dez/2031,mar/2032,jun/2032,set/2032,dez/2032,mar/2033,jun/2033,set/2033,dez/2033,mar/2034,jun/2034,set/2034,dez/2034,mar/2035,jun/2035,set/2035,dez/2035,mar/2036,jun/2036,set/2036,dez/2036,mar/2037,jun/2037,set/2037,dez/2037,mar/2038,jun/2038,set/2038,dez/2038,mar/2039,jun/2039,set/2039,dez/2039,mar/2040,jun/2040,set/2040,dez/2040"
End With
End Sub
```

I want that once that code is executed, that list remains in existence if I close and reopen the spreadsheet.

Thank you very much

Comment: What happens presently if you close & reopen the file? Before you close the file, have you *saved* it?

Comment: Yes, I run the macro and save.
When I reopen the spreadsheet it is as if I had not run the macro, as the list disappears.

Comment: Why are not you creating just a list on Excel?